# Is hreflang tag required if site uses only one non English language?

Tags: seo, hreflang

I have site with Thailand language as a default and no other switching languages. In this case Do I need to configure `hreflang` option still for SEO purpose?

Comment: Done. Your answer is Generic and this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your website is only written in one language, you don't need any `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="" href="">` tags.

Just open your html element with the proper language code that you're targeting, like this:

```
<html lang="th">
```

Comment: Thank you Maximillian. Also assuming if Google Search Console shows warning for hreflang enabling, we no need consider this and it won't impact search ranking. Am I correct?

Comment: What specific warning are you seeing? Does the warning tell you that you need hreflang but don't currently have it?